# bootstrap navbar doesn't show up when I hit the toggler icon

Tags: bootstrap-4, toggle, navbar, angular-ui-bootstrap, togglebutton

I have a simple question about the bootstrap navbar toggler. The toggler does appear when the window gets smaller, but when I click it the navbar doesn't appear. Wondering if someone could take a quick look at my code and point out something that might be missing. Relatively new to bootstrap so any help is much appreciated !!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  ">
    <a class="navbar-brand">MY NAME HERE</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/blogs">LinkedIn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

```
nav {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 70px !important;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

a {
    background-color: white;

}

div {
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.nav-link {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code. It works just fine. The navbar requires a ['collapse plugin'](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#how-it-works) in order to provide expected results. So make sure that you bootstrap javascript files are being loaded correctly, and the plugin is included the build you're using.